# ES6 findIndex to return highest number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use the ES6 `findIndex()` method to return the highest number. How do I do that? In this example below, I simply want to return the index with the highest ID.

```
let index = context.state.locations.findIndex((l) => {l.id ??????  });
```

Comment: you can do it via this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilagarwal530/np9L66bv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for simple solution. Using [`Array#findindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) it would more be complex.

Set the initial value as `0`(starting index) assume the first element holds the larger `id` value. Within the callback compare current larger id value(based on the current maxIndex) with current element and return index based on the larger value.

```
let index = context.state.locations.reduce((maxIndex, obj, curIndex, arr) => arr[maxIndex].id < obj.id ? curIndex : maxIndex, 0);
```

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 23
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 27
}, {
  id: 5
}, {
  id: 58
}, {
  id: 50
}];

let index = arr.reduce((maxIndex, obj, curIndex, arr) => arr[maxIndex].id < obj.id ? curIndex : maxIndex, 0);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: This works great. I wish I understood *how* it works!

Answer (score 1):

You have to check all items for greater `id` and use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var array = [{ id : 3 }, { id : 42 }, { id : 2 }, { id : 15 }, { id : 13 }, { id : 99 }, { id : 1 }],
    index = array.reduce( (r, a, i, aa) => aa[r].id > a.id ? r : i, 0);

console.log(index);
console.log(array[index]);
```